# falcon module installed but not being detected

Tags: python-3.x, pip

```
ishandutta2007@MacBook-Pro:~/Documents/Projects/tacotron2_dacson_ishandutta2007$ pip freeze
astroid==1.6.5
audioread==2.1.6
backports.functools-lru-cache==1.5
configparser==3.5.0
cycler==0.10.0
decorator==4.3.0
enum34==1.1.6
falcon==1.4.1
funcsigs==1.0.2
functools32==3.2.3.post2
futures==3.2.0
inflect==0.2.5
isort==4.3.4
joblib==0.12.5
lazy-object-proxy==1.3.1
librosa==0.5.1
llvmlite==0.25.0
matplotlib==2.0.2
mccabe==0.6.1
numba==0.40.1
numpy==1.13.0
pylint==1.9.3
pyparsing==2.2.2
python-dateutil==2.7.3
python-mimeparse==1.6.0
pytz==2018.5
resampy==0.2.1
scikit-learn==0.20.0
scipy==0.19.0
singledispatch==3.4.0.3
six==1.11.0
subprocess32==3.5.3
tqdm==4.11.2
Unidecode==0.4.20
wrapt==1.10.11
(env342) ishandutta2007@MacBook-Pro:~/Documents/Projects/tacotron2_dacson_ishandutta2007$ python3 demo_server.py --checkpoint pretrained/tacotron-20170720/model.ckpt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo_server.py", line 2, in <module>
    import falcon
ImportError: No module named 'falcon'
(env342) ishandutta2007@MacBook-Pro:~/Documents/Projects/tacotron2_dacson_ishandutta2007$
```

The python virtual enviroment is of python 3.4.2

Comment: What's the output of `which pip`?

Comment: (env342) ishandutta2007@MacBook-Pro:~/Documents/Projects/tacotron2_dacson_ishandutta2007$ which pip
/Users/ishandutta2007/Documents/Projects/tacotron2_dacson_ishandutta2007/env342/bin/pip

Comment: Your `pip` most likely targets a different Python version's `site-packages`. Check the output of: `python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"` to see where your `python3` is getting its modules from.

Comment: (env342) ishandutta2007@MacBook-Pro:~/Documents/Projects/tacotron2_dacson_ishandutta2007$ python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
['', '/Users/ishandutta2007/Documents/Projects/tacotron2_dacson_ishandutta2007', '/Users/ishandutta2007/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python34.zip', '/Users/ishandutta2007/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4', '/Users/ishandutta2007/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/plat-darwin', '/Users/ishandutta2007/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', '/Users/ishandutta2007/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages']

Comment: (env342) ishandutta2007@MacBook-Pro:~/Documents/Projects/tacotron2_dacson_ishandutta2007$ `pyenv version`
3.4.2 (set by /Users/ishandutta2007/Documents/Projects/tacotron2_dacson_ishandutta2007/.python-version)